# How can I find the last access time of a redis key?

Tags: redis

In redis, two of the eviction policies, allkeys-lru and volatile-lru, evict keys based on access time. So, this information must exist somewhere. Is it possible for me to query the access time of a key? Or, better yet, page through a sorted list of keys based on access time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at [Object IDLETIME](http://redis.io/commands/object) it gives time for which the object was idle

as guided by @Itamar Haber  the way they disable some command is by using redis.conf

```
# It is also possible to completely kill a command by renaming it into
# an empty string:
#
rename-command FLUSHDB ""
rename-command FLUSHALL ""
rename-command DEBUG ""
```

As you are using Redis as a service on Heroku you have to have admin rights to do this 
Hope this helps!

Comment: "ERR unknown command 'OBJECT'" -- this is on a heroku redis instance

Comment: `OBJECT IDLETIME foo`

Comment: This command is available since  2.2.3. can you check your redis version?

Comment: the version is 3.2.1

Comment: Many Redis providers protect their service by disabling chosen Redis commands - `OBJECT` is one such common example.